# Hashtag in URL in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a search input for customers. The customers have an address, and some of the addresses contain the number sign, for example `#51 Scout Fuentebella`. I included address in my search.

My route:

```
Route::get('customer/search/{input}', 'CustomerController@search');
```

Whenever I search for their address like **localhost:8000/customer/search/#51 Sc**, I get the following error:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: Everything after `#` (including the character itself) does not get sent to the server.

Comment: Is there a way to include hash?

Comment: No. The hash is only relevant for the client (it's used for the `a` anchor).

Comment: Okay, maybe I'll check if there is a hash in input or not then, remove it and do the search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hash mark (`#`) has special meaning inside of a url. It marks the start of the [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and is only handled on the client side. Nothing after the `#` will be sent to the server.

If your url needs to have a hash inside of it, then you need to urlencode the data before building the url.

`#` encodes to `%23`, so for your example, `localhost:8000/customer/search/%2351%20Sc` should work fine.