# Laravel - Get fragment from URL

Tags: laravel

I am receiving an auth code from Microsoft that looks like this:

```
localhost:8000/token#auth=123456
```

In Laravel I have a route that points to a controller:

```
Route::get('/token', 'AuthController@getToken');
```

The function looks like this:

```
public function getToken(Request $request) {

  session([
    'request' => $request->fullUrl(),
  ]);

}
```

The problem is that `fullUrl()` returns `localhost:8000/token` so I can't see the auth token.

Is there a way round this?

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096358/hashtag-in-url-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you get that URL as a string, you can use [parse_​url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the fragment part:

```
<?php
$url = 'localhost:8000/token#auth=123456';
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
```

will output: `string(11) "auth=123456"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value after the hash mark (`#`) as shown in a user's browser: This isn't possible with **"standard" HTTP** as this value is never sent to the server (hence it won't be available in `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` or similar predefined variables). You would need some sort of JavaScript magic on the client side, e.g. to include this value as a POST parameter.

So when you call :

```
localhost:8000/token#auth=123456
```

Your server get this :

```
localhost:8000/token
```

The browser delete everything from the hash (`#`) of your url, then it pass to the server http process